# Jquery Validate which image clicked

Tags: jquery, validation, rule

I have a form with 5 icons and I want to validate which one is clicked. I thought to add a hidden text box and write a rule which checks the value of it. This works on form submit, but I need the error message to be cleared on clicking the correct image. At the moment, the validation is not fired when the text value is changed by javascript. Any better way of doing this?

```
<form name="frmExperiment" id="frmExperiment" action="" method="post">
<img src="btn1.png" width="75" height="75" alt="continue" title="continue" onclick="frmExperiment.txtIconG.value=1" />
<img src="btn2.png" width="75" height="74" alt="information" title="information" onclick="frmExperiment.txtIconG.value=2" />
<img src="btn3.png" width="75" height="82" alt="refresh" title="refresh" onclick="frmExperiment.txtIconG.value=3" />
<img src="btn4.png" width="75" height="75" alt="home" title="home" onclick="frmExperiment.txtIconG.value=4" />
<img src="btn6.png" width="75" height="77" alt="stop" title="stop" onclick="frmExperiment.txtIconG.value=5" />
<input type="text" name="txtIconG" id="txtIconG" />
</form>
```

and

```
$.validator.addMethod("iconmatch", function (value, element) {
return value==1;
},
"That isn't the continue button"
);
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be '(value==1)'?

Comment: return value==1 will return true or false.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("img").bind("click", function(){
  var whichImg = $(this).attr("title");
  if( whichImg == "continue" ) {
   // do stuff or submit the form
  } else {
     var txt = "That isnt the continue button! You've clicked the "+ whichImg + " button!";
     $("#txtIconG").val( txt );
  }
  return false;
});
```

Comment: Bob, thanks, how would I tie that in to the validation though?

Comment: It is now validating wheter you've clicked the right button, mate! You don't even need the onclick's in your html tags!

Comment: I cut the form down for brevity - there's a pile of other form elements which need validated before submission. That's why I want to do this using a custom rule

Comment: Okay, then add the other validators with if-statements in the "//do stuff or submit the form" section.

Answer (score 0):

Give an id to each img and on click of each id you do what ever you want .
I hope id of img shud work other wise put a span or div for each img and give id to them

```
$('#target').click(function() {
  alert('Handler for .click() called.');
});
```

Comment: I can detect which img is clicked by `$('#frmExperiment img').click(function(){alert($(this).attr('src'));});` but I don't know how to tie it into a custom rule

Answer (score 0):

Sorted. The problem was that changing the value by js onclick doesn't fire the validation. So, I removed the onclicks and in jQuery added:

```
$('#frmExperiment img').click(function(){
    $('#txtIconG').val($(this).attr('src'));
    $('#txtIconG').keyup();
});
```

and in the custom rule:

```
$.validator.addMethod("iconmatch", function (value, element) {
    return value=='btn1.png';
},
    "That isn't the continue button"
);
```

So, firing the keyup event on the input did the job. There may be a more elegant way of doing this, but it's working...